# How can I seperate routes in different modules and initialize with one line of code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

***What and why***

A little background why I want the following. First of all I want to create a website and a content management system. I want to seperate my routes in two modules (the website and CMS) because I find it cleaner code and more maintainable for the future. In my app.js/server.js file I want to initialize these routes with one line of code: 'routeWebsitePages.initialize()'.

I made the following:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
var routesWebsitePages = require('./routes/website/pages.js');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('./assets'));
app.use(express.static('./node_modules/material-design-lite'));

nunjucks.configure('views', {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app
});

routesWebsitePages.initialize();

app.listen(3000);
```

**routes/website/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports = {
    router: express.Router()
}
```

**routes/website/pages.js**

```
var modules = require('./index.js');

module.exports = {

    initialize: function () {
        this.routes.forEach((item) => {
            modules.router.route(item.path).get(item.action);
        });
    },

    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            action: function (req, res, next) {
                res.render('index.html', {
                    // Data to send to index.html
                    'helloWorld': 'Hello World'
                });
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

***Cannot GET /***

I think I have done something wrong in the routes/website/index.js file. When I go to localhost:3000 I get the following message 'Cannot GET /'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must pass app to routes or return route table and join it to app

```
routesWebsitePages.initialize(app);
```

or

```
app.use(routesWebsitePages.initialize());
```